# log(n) vs. constant time

Tags: data-structures, big-o

`HashSet` class has a constant time performance for the basic operations (`add`, `remove`, `contains` and `size`).

`TreeSet` has `log(n)` time cost for the basic operations (`add`, `remove` and `contains` methods).

Because `HashSet` is constant, will it always be faster than `log(n)` ?

Comment: `HashSet` is `O(n)`. Its best case is `O(1)`.

Comment: You also have to consider the number of operations you're doing over time to see the value in different algorithms.

Comment: They are not like A > B, they have somewhat different properties. TreeSet maintains ordering, HashSet does not. Also, why did you use android tag? This is nothing android-specific.

Comment: constant time is better than log(n) time in most cases.  In edge cases where log(n) is smaller than the constant it will be faster (in the real world).  Remember that one billion and 1 are both "constant" in big O notation.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not how big-Oh works.  Actual performance may differ.

Bubble sort is notoriously slow, but for a small data set it might actually perform well compared to other "better" algorithms.  The big-Oh describes asymptotic behavior, not specific individual scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

There are some weasel words in the API documentation for HashSet: "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), **assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets**" (emphasis mine). In the worst case HashSet reduces to a linked list, giving linear performance for those methods.

This performance degradation was the cause of a bunch of security vulnerabilities:
https://www.securityweek.com/hash-table-collision-attacks-could-trigger-ddos-massive-scale
in which (say) connections were put into a hash table where [some of] the inputs to the hash function were under the attacker's control. This led to theoretically-constant-time operations taking linear time.

TreeSet however "provides **guaranteed** log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)".

So: HashSet's operations ought to be quicker, so long as your hash function provides a uniform distribution of hash values and your inputs are suitably random with respect to that distribution. But in terms of guaranteed performance it's O(n).

Comment: That's *not* what amortized means. Amortized O(1) time would be n operations taking O(n) time even though some of those operations might take more (e.g. O(n)) time. "Average" is the correct technical term, and "amortized" is not a synonym for it (plus, it refers to the case, not the kind of bound for some case).

Comment: actually, on reflection I'm not sure that "average" is correct. Since some ops will be worse than O(1) (i.e. when hash collisions occur), we can only "average" O(1) if some ops are faster, which isn't possible. *Most* ops will be O(1) given the above assumptions about hash function behaviour, but I'm not sure that you can make any non-arm-waving statements about "average" performance.

Comment: @user3392484 you're correct, You cannot say that hash containers are O(1) on average.  However, your reasoning for _why_ is wrong, you _can_ average O(1) even when some ops are O(n) and none are faster than O(1), if the `n` only happens every `n` elements (hard to explain, but C++ `std::vector` does this.)

Comment: @MooingDuck No, no, you're also confusing the average case and the amortized complexity.

Comment: @user3392484 Average here means: In the average case, i.e. for the average inputs, i.e. for the average keys (assuming a decent hash function). From the precise definition of "decent hash function" it follows that, among all possible key sets, key sets giving excessive collisions (i.e. worse enough to cause linear slowdown) are by far the minority, enough to make a rigorous mathematical case for the "average O(1) time" claim.

Comment: @delnan: I'm not confusing them, but it is possible I have a misunderstanding of one or the other.  I think that for algorithms where an amortized performance exists, it is always equal to the average performance for a series of operations.  It doesn't seem like it ought to be true, but I can't think of evidence that it's false.

Comment: @delnan - OK, makes sense. But I was thinking of "average" in terms of "if I make some large number of ops then the average performance per op is ..."; I don't think that you can say O(1) for "...", because you'll get a small number of hash collisions. You can make a probabilistic argument (along the lines of Pr(collision) = p, so Pr(constant time) = 1-p for some random input hence random key, so make p small by choosing a decent hash function and making your table large), but that's not quite the same? (This is all telling me that I should dig out a textbook or two, but it's gone 10pm here!)

Comment: @MooingDuck You must be confusing *something*, since they are completely different beasts. The "average performance for a series of operations" *is* the amortized complexity; *average(-case) complexity* is the cost of *one* operation. Although both are often explained using the word "average", in the case of average-case it's the *average input* and for amortization it's the *average operation*. You can make a 2D categorization from these: What's the amortized/non-amortized cost in the best/average/worst case each?

Comment: @user3392484 "The average performance per op" is the amortized cost. But amortized analysis needs a case, you need to assume some inputs. Average case complexity is indeed a probabilistic argument (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity), which is indeed a different thing, but useful in its own right. It tells you that the odds of worst-than-constant complexity is negligible, *if* the assumptions of the proof (properties of hash function; probability distribution function of keys) are fulfilled.